# Why does using this code can generate a random password?

Tags: python, random, cryptography, passwords

Here a snippet for generating password code,
I have 2 questions about this, Could you please share how to understand?

1. `urandom(6)`, help from urandom said,return n random bytes suitable for cryptographic use, it is say, it will return 6 bytes, is it 6 of ASCII ?
2. `ord(c)` , get the decimal base for above bytes, why here transfer to decimal base?

Help for `urandom`:

```
def urandom(n): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
    """
    urandom(n) -> str

    Return n random bytes suitable for cryptographic use.
    """
    return ""
```

Python script:

```
from os import urandom
letters = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZ"
password = "".join(letters[ord(c) % len(letters)] for c in urandom(6))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`urandom` will return a byte (i.e. a value between 0 and 255). The sample code uses that value and the modulo operator (`%`) to convert it into a value between 0 and 22, so that it can return one of the 23 letters (`I`, `O`, and `Q` are excluded not to be confused with numbers).

Note that it is not a perfectly balanced algorithm as it would favour the first 3 letters (`A`, `B`, and `C`) more, because 256 is not divisible by 23 and `256 % 23` is `3`.

Comment: Very appreciated for Selcuk's much details and quick explanation,very useful!

Answer (score 1):

`ord()` function takes in a string containing a single character, and returns its Unicode index.

ex.

```
ord("A") => 65
ord("£") => 163
```

It is not used to get the decimal base of a byte as you mentioned, but rather its Unicode Index (its place in the Unicode Table).

**P.S. :-** Even though it returns the Unicode index but that doesn't mean its, range = len(Unicode Table) , the reason being that your python compiler may not support such long character sets under normal circumstances.